# how to ranking document inner array object with mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document design for ranking user's activity in every month.
Every user has a ranking recorder like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId //user id
    month_record:[
        {
            month: "2016-08",
            sum: 100
        },
        {
            month: "2016-09",
            sum: 100
        },
        ...
    ]
    sum: 1400
}
```

I have attempt to search a specify month ranking(top 30) with:

```
db.getCollection('activities')
    .find({"month_record.month": {"$eq":"2016-08"}})
    .sort({"month_record.$.sum":-1}).limit(30)
```

and

```
db.getCollection('activities')
    .find().sort({"month_record.month": {"$eq":"2016-08"},"month_record.$.sum":-1})
    .limit(30)`
```

but all of them not works.
How to ranking with specify month?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way to solve that is by aggregation framework:

```
db.activities.aggregate([{
        $match : {
            "month_record.month" : {
                "$eq" : "2016-08"
            }
        }
    }, {
        $unwind : "$month_record"
    }, {
        $match : {
            "month_record.month" : {
                "$eq" : "2016-08"
            }
        }
    }, {
        $sort : {
            "month_record.sum" : -1
        }
    }, {
        $limit : 30
    }
])
```

===================

## **EDIT**

```
{
    "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
    "stages" : [ 
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {},
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "test.lorence",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : []
                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                            "$and" : []
                        },
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : []
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$unwind" : {
                "path" : "$month_record"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$match" : {
                "month_record.month" : {
                    "$eq" : "2016-08"
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$sort" : {
                "sortKey" : {
                    "month_record.sum" : -1
                },
                "limit" : NumberLong(30)
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

as this is dump of execution plan `{explain:true}` it shows that index is not used in this case.

Any comments welcome!

Comment: I forget a question, does it have performs problem if I have thousand(or billions) users?I noticed form [mongo document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) `$match` will benefit form indexes if it placed at the beginning of the pipeline, also `$sort` does.This situation can't use indexes,it's my consider just now.

Comment: match should be used as a 1 and 3 step. 1 will select only records having given month and as it is used as a first step, index should be used.

Comment: but match at step 2, its't it?

Comment: consider my specify situation: every document has `month_record.month == "2016-08"` because the sum will be 0 if he not participate any activity, so the first `$match` not filter anything actually.

Comment: em...It just seems some odd. future more, which indexes should I append for the aggregate?such as `month_record.month` for `$match`, `month_record` for `$unwind`, I'm not sure does them works.